# Get value from post meta array, and add it as a category

Tags: post-meta, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a form that performs an AJAX hook that does several things, one of them is that it takes some form fields, adds them to an array, and adds that array as meta to the post that is created from the form.

In the AJAX function, it looks like this:

```
// get form data array (we already have $post_id set)
$data_cf = $_POST['form_data'];
// update post meta (post is the newly created fundraiser from above)
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_cf_data', $data_cf ); 

// set some stuff from form data array
$data_cf_country = $data_cf['country'];
$data_cf_city    = $data_cf['city'];
$data_cf_state   = $data_cf['state'];
```

then I need to add each of the above to their respective categories/taxonomies for the post. Ex: the values could be United States, Chicago, Illinois, which would be added to Country, City, State.

I have the taxonomies registered already for the post. I just can't seem to find out how to add the post to them at this step.

Tips? Thanks!

Comment: Look at [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had thought, but I'm getting 

WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array (
  [invalid_taxonomy] => Array (
       [0] => Invalid taxonomy
   )
  )
  [error_data] => Array ( )
)

Comment: Which are taxonomies you have registered? What is the code you used? please, update the question.

Comment: My apologies. I had registered the taxonomy incorrectly. set_object_terms is getting me there now, thanks!